# How to display three whiptail on the same screen?

Tags: bash, gnu-screen, whiptail

I have three very long processes that I need to monitor. Rather than having three terminal windows open each with a separate whiptail progress bar. I am searching for a way to send three whiptail progress bar output to a single terminal using screen or tmux? Is this possible?

For example, I need the following output sent to three times to the terminal screen at the same time.

```
#!/bin/bash
{
  DEPLOYING=0;
  while [ "$DEPLOYING" -le "100" ]; do
      DEPLOYING=$(deploy $ENVIRONMENT)
  done
} | whiptail --gauge "Deploying application to $ENVIRONMENT environment..." 6 50 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following tmux example:

```
tmux -f /dev/null \
 new-session -s mywhiptail 'mycmd 1' \; \
 split-window -v -l 8 -t 0 'mycmd 3' \; \
 split-window -v -l 8 -t 0 'mycmd 2'
tmux kill-session -t mywhiptail
```

where `mycmd` is your script running whiptail. I added an optional parameter (1,2, or 3) to show you in which order you need to give the commands if you want them to appear in the right order on the screen.  `-l 8` sets the window height for the whiptail to 8 lines; you may want to vary this.